# Anybody else find Visual Studio 2012 hard to read?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I find the new UI very hard to look at after a few minutes. They seem to have gone to give it a low-contrast look so reading the text is very difficult.

Anybody found a workaround to get a VS2010 look but still take advantage of the new stuff in .net 4.5?

Answer (score 2):

1. Change theme to Light to Dark. (Options > Environment > General)
2. Change toolbar font / BG colour. (Options > Environment > Fonts & Colours)
3. Try to use [themes](http://www.riverblade.co.uk/blog.php?archive=2012_08_01_archive.xml#2012080202#2012080202).